# Wrong data output on basic select condition

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm trying to get the values which Dates bigger then 2021-07-17 and Cities starting with 'G'. I have id in the PERSON table, id (references from PERSON(id)) and date in VACCDATA table, id (references from PERSON(id)) and city in ADDRESS table.

```
SELECT p.id, v.vac_date, a.city
FROM PERSON AS p
LEFT JOIN VACCDATA AS v
ON v.vac_date > '2021-07-17' AND v.id=p.id
LEFT JOIN ADDRESS AS a
ON a.city LIKE 'G%' AND a.id=v.id;


  

          ID       DATE        CITY

Row 1 --> 15 ; "2021-07-19" ; ""

Row 2 --> 18 ; "2021-07-18" ; "Giresun"

Row 3 --> 17 ; "" ; ""
```

While i only want the Row 2 (because it's city name is starts with 'G' and Date is bigger then 2021-07-17 at the same time), it gives the above output. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: why left join? use inner join instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `LEFT JOIN` with the conditions on the join itself. So you get all persons from database no matter the criteria is matching.

You can use `INNER JOIN` with `WHERE` filter instead:

```
SELECT p.id, v.vac_date, a.city
FROM PERSON AS p
  INNER JOIN VACCDATA AS v ON v.id = p.id
  INNER JOIN ADDRESS AS a ON a.id = v.id
WHERE v.vac_date > '2021-07-17' AND a.city LIKE 'G%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply join with condition, then first make relationship between tables and the add condition.

First make relationship `v.id = p.id` and then add condition `v.vac_date > '2021-07-17'`

```
SELECT p.id, v.vac_date, a.city
FROM PERSON AS p
  INNER JOIN VACCDATA AS v ON v.id = p.id AND v.vac_date > '2021-07-17'
  INNER JOIN ADDRESS AS a ON a.id = v.id AND a.city LIKE 'G%'
```